# Remove single items/QLineF's from QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, drawing, qgraphicsscene

I have drawn a grid into a `qgraphicsscene` with `QLineF`'s and you can add custom `qgraphicsitems` into the scene as blocks in the grid. I want to be able to redraw the grid with different spacing and indexing (indexes are just thicker lines).

My problem is I do not know how to just remove the lines. I can remove everything from the scene but that takes too much work because I have to copy all my custom items into an array and then re-add them to the scene. I tried making a list of pointers into the lines but I can't delete the pointers. I also thought about adding the lines as children to a `qgraphicsitem` and deleting that item which would result into the deletion of all the lines but you can't set parents to the lines.

How do I remove specific line components from a `QGraphicsScene`?

**Like this: `scene->removeItem(..pointer..);` I was incorrectly catching the result of `scene->addItem(..)` as an object and then storing it's &reference. When I store the result as a pointer I was able to manipulate the item again.**

Comment: "...but I can't delete the pointers." Why?  When you use `QGraphicsScene::addLine(..)` it returns a pointer to the line, are you using this?

Comment: I create an QLineF object and then a pointer to that object, I push it back to an vector. I suppose using the returned pointer would be the same? When later I iterate through the vector I try to delete it like this: `QLineF* grab = linevector.at(i); delete grab; grab = NULL;`

Comment: I'm confused, how are you getting the `QLineF`s into the scene?

Comment: Through scene's addLine() function. But is this even a working concept, if I terminate the LineF will the Scene recognize that and erase it or would it crash?

Comment: If I've understood you correctly: neither.  `QGraphicsLineItem` contains a `QLineF`, so when you create one using `QGraphicsScene::addLine(..)` the line data is just copied into it.  However if you delete the `QGraphicsLineItem`, it will remove itself from the scene.

Comment: I do not know how to delete it through the pointer, frustrating.. ´QGraphicsLineItem* grab;´ Isn't it `delete grab;`? I get access violation. I even tried calling the destructor `grab->~QGraphicsLineItem();`

Comment: `QGraphicsLineItem* line = scene->addLine( myLine ); /* Do stuff...  Then later on: */delete line;`

Comment: Assertion failiure even if I put those two lines back to back. I'm just going to create a new scene everytime and move the stuff there and delete the old scene. This is retarded.

Comment: `"BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)"`

Comment: I no longer expect further help, thanks for the assist. There's a curious development though, in a thread I am able to delete these lines through `removeItem(..)` -- I need to find out why it doesn't work in my problem. Sorry I can't give you any rep due my low-level account.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a QGraphicsItemGroup - http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitemgroup.html, something like...

```
void Grid::addVerticalLineAt(qreal xCoord)
{
    QRectF sceneRect = scene()->sceneRect();
    QGraphicsLineItem* line = scene()->addLine(xCoord, mapFromScene(sceneRect.top()), xCoord, mapFromScene(sceneRect.bottom()));
    (QGraphicsItemGroup*)(this->gridLines)->addToGroup(line);
}
void Grid::Refresh(qreal p_Scale)
{
    delete this->gridLines;                     //deletes all lines underneath
    gridLines = new QGraphicsItemGroup(this);   //construct this _before_ you start calling addXXXLineAt
    qreal spacing = BASIC_SPACING * p_Scale;
    for(qreal curXCoord = sceneRect.left(); curXCoord < sceneRect.right(); curXCoord += spacing) //each spaced point in scenerect 
    {
        addVerticalLineAt(curXCoord);
    }
}
```

... should work.

Another approach would be to just add another QGraphicsItem called Grid, and assign all the QLineFs to that item, by setting the parent in the QGraphicsLineItem ctor.